# Microsoft graph api group alias

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to set alias email while creating a Unified group using the graph api and also keep the group private (members only) default seems to be public.

Also, is it possible to get the id of the group using the alias.

thanks

Actually wanted the alias in a sub-domain

example: group email is  XX_library@test.com and alias library@XX.test.com

Is this possible?

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set alias email while creating a Unified group using
>   the graph api and also keep the group private (members only) default
>   seems to be public.

The **mailNickname** should be the field which you can set the alias email.
The **visibility** is the field which you can set the public/private.

```
{
  "description": "Self help community for library1",
  "displayName": "Library1 Assist",
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ],
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "library1",
  "securityEnabled": false,
   "visibility": "private"
}
```

> Also, is it possible to get the id of the group using the alias.

```
   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=mailNickname eq 'library'&$select=id
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#groups(id)",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "b471f3f2-90d5-4d48-9770-fa4df7132324"
        }
    ]
}
```